# Error Message: TOK_ALLCOLREF is not supported in current context - while Using DISTINCT in HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, distinct, bigdata

I'm using the simple command: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM first_working_table;`  in HIVE 0.11, and I'm receiving the following error message:

> FAILED: SemanticException TOK_ALLCOLREF is not supported in current
>   context.

Does anyone know why this is happening? How can we solve it?

Thank you,
Gal.

Answer (score 41):

Hive doesn't support `DISTINCT *` syntax. You can manually specify every field of the table to get the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, ...., fieldN
  FROM first_working_table
```

Comment: This is the easiest way or can be called as work-around to fix the problem.

Answer (score 10):

As specified in earlier comment distinct * not supported. Which is true.
One trick can be like this.

Distinct * can be used in this fashion:

```
select distinct * from (
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t2.* from t1,t2
)tbl;
```

I have used this syntax in Hive 2.x. So I can confirm that this works.

Answer (score 0):

There is one trick:

```
Select distinct * from (select * from tableA)abc
```

Weird but yes it works!